# Get all rows from group by query

Tags: android, sqlite, group-by

I have database sqlite contain 2 tables:

**names**

[image: Table with two columns. The column id contains numbers and the column name contains strings.]

**n_data**

[image: Table with three columns. The column id contains numbers, the column name_id contains numbers, and the column value contains strings.]

and query:

```
select 
    n_data.id,n_data.value, count( n_data.id) as count 
from 
    n_data 
INNER JOIN names on names.id = n_data.name_id 
group by 
    n_data.name_id 
order by 
    n_data.id asc
```

In activity I have used 
Cursor and while

```
 while (res.moveToNext()) {
      System.out.println("id=>"+res.getString(0)+" count=>"+res.getString(2)+" =value=>"+res.getString(1));
 }
```

but result just show last row in group. How can I get all rows for every group?

```
CREATE TABLE "names" (
    id  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,  
    name    TEXT );
INSERT INTO names (id,name) VALUES  
(1,'name_1'),  
(2,'name_2'),  
(3,'name_3'),  
(4,'name_4');  
CREATE TABLE "n_data" (
    id  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,  
    name_id TEXT,  
    value   TEXT );  
INSERT INTO n_data (id,name_id,value) VALUES  
(1,'3','value_8'),  
(2,'2','value_7'),  
(3,'2','value_6'),  
(4,'2','value_5'),  
(5,'1','value_4'),  
(6,'1','value_3'),  
(7,'1','value_2'),  
(8,'1','value_1'),  
(9,'3','value_9');
```

Comment: Can you add to your mcve a `.dump` from sqlite commandline tool?

Comment: @Yunnosch sorry i did`t know how use sqlite command line

Comment: Very simple, download to a PC (no installation needed, but I do assume you have a PC) start with parameter filename of your sqlite database (which I assume you will find a way of gettting to your PC). Then you have access via SQL(ite) syntax to you database. There are some helpful "dot-commands", e.g. `.dump` for making StackOverflow mcve conveniently. But the main recommendation is to use it for getting an "unfiltered" view on your data. Since you basically know SQL syntax, it will be as easy to learn for you as a new toy for a kid for Christmas. Hmm, sounds like kidding, but is serious hint.

Comment: @Yunnosch   this sql fro database

CREATE TABLE "names" (
 `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 `name` TEXT
);
INSERT INTO `names` (id,name) VALUES (1,'name_1'),
 (2,'name_2'),
 (3,'name_3'),
 (4,'name_4');
CREATE TABLE "n_data" (
 `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 `name_id` TEXT,
 `value` TEXT
);
INSERT INTO `n_data` (id,name_id,value) VALUES (1,'3','value_8'),
 (2,'2','value_7'),
 (3,'2','value_6'),
 (4,'2','value_5'),
 (5,'1','value_4'),
 (6,'1','value_3'),
 (7,'1','value_2'),
 (8,'1','value_1'),
 (9,'3','value_9');

Comment: Hope you like the different view point on your data. Sometimes that is useful. And thanks for the info, makes understanding your question or answering easier.

Comment: I think more information on what you want ot achieve is necessary. Based on your database content, I think what you get matches your query. Can you describe in prose what you want and define the desired output? How should the result look like? For my preference, give desired output like it would look from commandline tool. Try replacing `n_data.value` by `group_concat(n_data.value)`. The result might be closer to what you want. But let me know what you want differently.

Comment: @Yunnosch thanks alot by group_concat i can get all values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP is satisfied by:

```
select 
    n_data.id,
    group_concat(n_data.value) as 'all values',
    count( n_data.id) as count
from
    n_data INNER JOIN names 
    on names.id = n_data.name_id
group by n_data.name_id
order by n_data.id asc;
```

It uses `group_concat(n_data.value)` instead of `n_data.value`.
I.e. all the data.value which get counted by `count(n_data.id)` are concatenated.

Output (`.headers on`, `.mode column` and `.width 3 32 6`; SQLite 3.18.0 2017-03-28) :

```
id   all values                        count
---  --------------------------------  ------
4    value_7,value_6,value_5           3
8    value_4,value_3,value_2,value_1   4
9    value_8,value_9                   2
```

The tailored `.width` is needed, otherwise for id 8, only 3 values are shown, though 4 are retrieved.